# Syntax-Error in INTO-Command with two MDB table columns

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-insert, oledbcommand

I am working on a small program which fuses two single databases (with the same data structure) to one.

Everything is working fine, but in one table of the three important tables of the horrible database the SQL `INSERT INTO` command isn't working how it should.

All the Info I get is that my Syntax is wrong.

The table looks like this (MySQL Syntax, guess thats the best way to show the table):

```
CREATE TABLE Images(
   Connect BIGINT,
   Number INT,
   ImageFile BIGINT,
   Side INT
)
```

Yes, it does not have a Primary Key nor a Foreign Key in this Table, even if `Connect` should be a ForeignKey and `ImageFile` should be a PrimaryKey. It is also not using `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I can execute the command `INSERT INTO Images (ImageFile) VALUES (12)` but it isn't possible to execute the command `INSERT INTO Images (Connect) VALUES (12)` because of the "Syntax Error". Same Error with "Number" and any combination which uses one of the two Error Columns.

I honestly don't know what is happening. I thought it might have something to do with the datatypes but this can't be the case since "Side" and "ImageFile" are working and "Number" and "Connect" isn't.

my executing testcode isn't that interesting, but I'll just leave this here:

```
masterCon.Close()
masterCon.ConnectionString =
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & tboxMaster.Text & "\database.mdb;"
Dim sqlCom = New OleDbCommand(TextBox1.Text, masterCon)
masterCon.Open()
Try
    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex)
End Try
masterCon.Close()
```

what could be the source of that problem?

Comment: Dollars to doughnuts that it's because connect and number are keywords.

Comment: that actually makes sense @DanBracuk ...how do I work around that? I unfortunately can't change the databases :/

Comment: You have to put the keywords in [brackets].

Comment: Your google search string is `ms access escape keywords`

Comment: oh my god. it worked. Thank you both very much. I didn't know I can do that.